# What's $H^*(X - \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\},\mathcal{O})$, when $X$ is a projective smooth surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over a field $k$.  Is there a way to compute $H^1(X - \{x\},\mathcal{O}_{X-\{x\}})$ in terms of similar invariants for $X$?  Actually I'd like to remove even more points, finitely many points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general reference for what follows is SGA 2, §1 to 4. Let $S\subset X$ be a finite subset, and $U:=X\smallsetminus S$. There is an exact sequence 
$$H^1_S(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^1(U,\mathcal{O}_U)\rightarrow H^2_S(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$$
Now $H^i_S(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=\bigoplus_{x\in S}H^i_{\{x\} }(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. This is zero for $i<2=\mathrm{depth}(\mathcal{O}_x)$, and $H^2_{\{x\} }(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a dualizing module over $\mathcal{O}_x$, hence infinite-dimensional over $k$. Thus $H^1(U,\mathcal{O}_U)$ is  infinite-dimensional over $k$, and can be described as an extension of the kernel of the homomorphism $\bigoplus_{x\in S}H^2_{\{x\} }(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\ $ by $\ H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: You mean $H^1(U,O_U)/H^1(X,O_X)$ is the kernel of this homomorphism.

Comment: Dear abx, what you write still looks incorrect:  I think that $H^1(U,\mathcal{O}_U)$ is an extension of the vector spaces you mention and  not a quotient.

Comment: Oops, right again! Many thanks, I edit.